# Should open any C file as a binary file

Tags: c, file, memory, binaryfiles

I've read somewhere we should always open file in C as a Binary file (even if it's a text file). At the time (few years ago) I didn't care too much about it, but now I really need to understand if that's the case and how come.

I've been trying to search for info on this but the most I find is the opening difference between them - not even their structural difference.

So I guess my question is: why should we always open the file as a binary even if we guess before hand it's a text file? Second question lies on the structure of each file itself, is a binary file like an "encrypted" text file?

Comment: I don't know where you've read that, but perhaps you *shouldn't*.

Comment: Take a look at this explanation: https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/FIO14-C.+Understand+the+difference+between+text+mode+and+binary+mode+with+file+streams

Comment: The more common rule of thumb is "use text mode for text files, binary mode for anything else" -- otherwise you have to deal with platform-specific line ending sequences in text files yourself. @Angew's answer already has nice examples explaining why.

Comment: A typical example where you'd deviate from this rule would be writing a text editor with the feature to convert between different line-endings (like e.g. vim does). To implement such a feature, you will of course need the actual verbatim contents of the file, so you have to open it in binary mode.

Comment: If you're dealing with file positions, you'll find that reading or writing `\n` in text mode on Windows will result in an increase of 2 characters since it reads/writes `\r\n` in actuality. In general, there's no need to concern yourself unless you intentionally want to deal with line endings. If you're concerned about reading a text file with Windows line endings on Linux or OS X, then you may want to consider dealing with line endings, in which case "always open file as a binary file" might be a good idea as this would allow for cross-platform compatibility in your code base.

Comment: Define what is a C file and then what is a file to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The names "text" vs. "binary", while quite mnemonic, can sometimes leave you wondering which one to apply. It's best to translate them to their underlying mechanics, and choose based on which one of *those* you need.

"Binary" could also be called "verbatim" opening mode. Each byte in the file will be read exactly as-is on disk. Which means that if it's a Windows file containing the text "ABC" on one line (including the line terminator), the bytes read from the file will be `65` `66` `67` `13` `10`.

"Text" mode could also be called "line-terminator translating" opening mode. When the file contains a sequence of 1 or more characters which is defined by the platform on which you're running as "line terminator"<sup>(1)</sup>, the entire sequence will be read from the file, but the runtime will make it appear as if only the character `'\n'` (`10` when using ASCII) was read. For the same Windows-file above, if it was opened as a text file on Windows, the bytes read from the file would be `65` `66` `67` `10`.

The same applies when writing: a file openend as "binary" for writing will write exactly the bytes you give it. A file opened as "text" will translate the byte `'\n'` (`10` in ASCII) to whatever the platform defines as the line-terminating character sequence.

I don't think an "always do this" rule can be distilled from the above, but perhaps you can use it to make an informed decision for each case.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> On Unix-style systems, the line-terminating character sequence is `LF` (ASCII `10`). On Windows, it's the two-character sequence `CR LF` (ASCII `13` `10`). On old pre-X Mac OS, it was just the single-character `CR` (ASCII `13`).

Comment: Another difference is that a special character whose value is ASCII 26 is inserted after the last character to mark the end of file for text files. Binary files don't have such special character, instead use a total number of characters.

Comment: @малинчекуров codepoint 26 as `EOF` is microsoft-specific and nowadays, text files don't have to end with such a character.